# How do I change the Currency Name in Magento?

Tags: magento, currency

Instead of it showing "British Pound Sterling - GBP" in the currency selector, I'd like it to just show "GBP - £" or "USD - $" etc. Anyone got any idea how to do this in magento? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

Answer (score 1):

Open
 `app/design/frontend/YOUR-PACKAGE/YOUR-THEME/template/directory/currency.phtml`

You will see the following code that will display: `Currency Name - Currency Code`

(e.g. `British Pound Sterling - GBP`)

```
<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
```

Your requirement is to display: `Currency Code - Currency Symbol`

(e.g. `GBP - £`)

So, you can do like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $_code )->getSymbol() ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ET_CurrencyManager extension will not help with this selector.

To modify this part you need to change template currency.phtml
This template is located in base theme here

```
    /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/directory/currency.phtml
```

but you need to copy this file to your theme or find this template in your theme

```
    /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR THEME/template/directory/currency.phtml
```

And then change the code

```
    <?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
```

to

```
    <?php echo $_code ?> - <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying my friend but it didnt fix the problem! I ended up changing `($_name)` to `($_code)` in the `/app/design/frontend/default/YOUR THEME/template/directory/currency-top.phtml` file

Answer (score 0):

You can do some rough coding here :P

modify the following file in your magento installation.

> /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR
>   THEME/template/directory/currency.phtml

```
switch($_code){
   case 'GBP':
   $symbol = '£';
   break;
   default:
   $symbol = '$';
}
//change the following line    
<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $_code ?> - <?php echo $symbol ?>
```